# How to open options (Dropdown) of each card when onclick function happens on the icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

i have two components one is icons.vue which contains icons in this component ,if i click on more-icon(fa-ellipse-v) it should open a dropdown it's working fine for me ,if i displayed(DisplayNotes.vue) all cards from backend (each card contains same icons which are coming from icons.vue),Now my problem is when i click on any card more icon means it's not opening the bar(Dropdown/options) on clicked-card instead of opening in same card it displays on the first card(Default card which is inside Notes[] array), i need to fix this issue if i click on any card it should open on that card only .please help me to fix this issue[[like this i need for each and every card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WYF9.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WYF9.png)

`icons.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="footer">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <i clss="fas fa-image"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <i @click="myFunction();" class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Delete Note</a>
            <a href="#">ChangeLabel</a>
            <a href="#">Add drawing</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.footer i {
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .fa-bell {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.footer .fa-user {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-palette {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-image {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-archive {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-ellipsis-v {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn {

    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(241, 234, 234)
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard" :cardContent="cardContent" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,
        UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
            clickedCard: '',
            cardContent: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id) {
            var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
            this.clickedCard = id;
            // this.card.content = this.notes.filter((note) => note.id === id);
            var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        },
        
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "colors";
.carddisplay-section{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.container {
    height: 180px;
    background: $dull_white;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #e0dede;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: -15%;
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
}
.card-content {
    h5 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 90%;
        height: 60px;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        padding: 7.5px 10px;
        outline: none;
    }
}
.card-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.note-icons {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.note {
    &:hover {
        .note-icons {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
.imported-icons {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#blur.active{
    filter:blur(0.5px);
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#popup{
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#popup.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.card-content p,h5 { 
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

When your template in `icons.vue` is used by your other template, it will get rendered multiple times, one per card. As a result, you will have multiple elements with the ID `myDropdown`, so when your `myFunction` function gets invoked, JavaScript is going to show the dropdown on the first card it finds with that ID. It is generally bad practice to have multiple HTML elements with the same ID, as it leads to situations such as this one.

To get around this, try using [Vue refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html), which allow you to uniquely identify a particular element within a Vue.JS template. Unlike regular IDs you'd access from/assign to an element in HTML or JavaScript, the `ref` of an element within a Vue template will be unique to that instance of the template. This is because refs are an internal property consumed by the Vue rendering engine rather than an explicit DOM property just tacked onto the element (like `style="..."` or `class="..."`, which are just tacked on and Vue doesn't change by default.)

Here is an example of how you may modify your code to do so:

```
<template>
<div class="footer">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <i clss="fas fa-image"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <i @click="myFunction();" class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        <div ref="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <!-- the 'ref' attribute will be consumed by Vue to identify this element -->
            <a href="#">Delete Note</a>
            <a href="#">ChangeLabel</a>
            <a href="#">Add drawing</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        myFunction(event) {
            this.$refs.myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
            // this.$refs.myDropdown will give us access to the dropdown element in this template
        }
    }
}
</script>
<!-- Your other code below here -->
```

Comment: ,Thanks a lot it's working ,The way u explained is too nice